# Как работают модификаторы g и n в f-строках?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Форматирование строк в python, не очень понятно как работают модификаторы `g` и `n`? В документации написано очень непонятно

Comment: Что именно в документации оказалось вам непонятно?

Comment: @andreymal в форматировании строк можно выбрать , или _ , какой смысл от n; и как выбирает g , что использовать f или e

Comment: вы конкретный пример в вопросе приведите. здесь вряд ли кто-то будет пересказывать вам документацию своими словами. правильно заданный вопрос - это половина ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Модификаторы форматирования строк g и n используются для форматирования числовых значений в строках в языке Python.

Модификатор g используется для вывода числовых значений в общем формате. Он автоматически выбирает наиболее короткий представимый формат для числа: либо обычный десятичный формат, либо экспоненциальный формат, если число очень маленькое или очень большое.

```
num1 = 1234.56789
num2 = 0.0000123456789
print("num1: {:g}, num2: {:g}".format(num1, num2))
```

Результат будет:

```
num1: 1234.57, num2: 1.23457e-05
```

Модификатор n используется для вывода числовых значений с разделителями групп разрядов. Этот модификатор вставляет запятые между каждыми тремя цифрами числа для удобства чтения.

```
num = 1234567890
print("num: {:,}".format(num))
```

Результат:

```
num: 1,234,567,890
```

Comment: `вставляет запятые` Ой ли?